# How to codesign Mac OSX executable without changing code behaviour

Tags: macos, code-signing, .app

I have a java-based executable (generated from java wrapper tool) which works on Mac OSX.

I am now trying package it for deployment in a MyApp.app form, including codesign this to allow it to be accepted by GateKeeper.

However when I codesign my executable within the "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS" driectory it changes how that executable runs - I get a ClassNotFoundException looking for the Java wrapper tool's specialised ClassLoader.

I realise this is probably an issue with the java wrapper tool's executable generation (and have raised an issue there), but is there was a way to avoid codesign impacting the executables operation?  I can use signtool on Windows with no problem.

I have had a look at "--detached" as a codesign option - to sign and generate a detached signature file. But the codesign verify I'm using to [test GateKeeper conformance](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG211) doesn't recognise this - I get "...is not signed at all".

Comment: Did you find any solution??????
I have a jar file and I want to package it in .app and then distribute it on MAC, how can I do that?????

Comment: @ManKeer - I haven't found a solution yet - my problem is specifically about (I think) the interaction between how my java wrapper creates the binary executable and then codesign changes it's behaviour.  If you are looking to deploy as .jar file then you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038674/1265200

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Actually I found a better answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable?noredirect=1&lq=1

javapackager is a great tool. and a well expalined steps can be founf in this tutorial:

https://centerkey.com/mac/java/