# How do I bundle a .jar file for MacOS?

Tags: javafx, deployment, launch4j, dmg

I have a working .jar file that I would like to package as a .dmg for MacOS.  I tried Launch4j, but quickly realized it only works for Windows .exe files.  Is there a MacOS alternative?  I do not need a JRE and also I should note that Gatekeeper is disabled so I do not need a Developer ID.  Any ideas?  It's for personal use so the only functionality I need is an icon I suppose.

Comment: See if anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037693/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214) helps. However, you may have to wait for the [`jpackage`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343) tool (replacement for `javapackager`) to be released (hopefully with Java 13) or use an [early access release](https://jdk.java.net/jpackage/) . Unless you're using Java 8, 9, or 10, in which case `javapackager` is still included with the JDK.

Comment: @Slaw This is great.  The one confusion I have is how to create and edit a plist file.  Should I do this through Eclipse?  Do you know of any documentation guiding one through the steps to create one?  I'm just not sure how much is necessary for it to be functional.  Again, I really just need an icon.