# How to distribute JAR app to apple MAC app store with xcode 13

Tags: jar, mac-app-store

I have JAR application ready.
i have apple account also. Please give me steps to signed app upload

Comment: See [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submitting/) for more info.

Comment: Modern tooling: [*JEP 282: jlink: The Java Linker*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282) and [*JEP 392: Packaging Tool*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392). Learn the [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System)

Answer (score 0):

**Distribute apps in the MACOS App Store**

This is the general workflow for publishing an app to the App Store using App Store Connect:

Step 1: Choose your build:
Each app can have multiple versions, and each version can have multiple builds. To publish your app on the App Store, [choose which build to submit to review](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7cbda8c55).

Step 2: Set pricing and availability:
You must set a price and set a tax category for your app. Although your app is available in all App Stores and localizations by default, you can select specific regions for your app instead. You also have the option to publish your app as a pre-order.

Step 3: Submit your app for review:
You [submit your app for review](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev301cb2b3e) to start the [App Review](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/) process and to make your app available on the App Store. Before you submit an app, [enter all the required metadata](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devfc3066644) and choose if you want to [release your app manually](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devabbb787a6) or automatically, or if you want to release your app in phases.

Step 4: Request promo codes:
After your app is approved, you can request promo codes to distribute to users before you make your app available on the App Store. You can distribute the promo codes by email or other means, and the user enters the promo code when purchasing the app.

Step 5: View your app status and resolve review issues:
After you submit the app, the app status changes to Waiting for Review. If there are any issues with your app, [read and reply to App Review communications](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7f7f86006). After your app is approved, it can take up to 24 hours to go live on the App Store.

**Outside the Mac App Store**

While the Mac App Store is the safest place for users to get software for their Mac, you may choose to distribute your Mac apps in other ways. Gatekeeper on macOS helps protect users from downloading and installing malicious software by checking for a Developer ID certificate. Make sure to test your apps with the latest version of macOS and sign your apps, plug-ins, or installer packages to let Gatekeeper know they’re safe to install.

In the comments there are a few useful links (reputation doesn't allowed me to put them here). ;-)

Comment: I would have prefered to add you more links in the step by step explanation, but I don't have enough reputation... >_<

Comment: Here there are a few useful links:
[Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac \[Oracle\]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)
[App Store Connect](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev34e9bbb5a)
[Submitting apps to the Mac App Store](https://developer.apple.com/macos/submit/)
[Convert Java application to Mac OS X app \[StackOverflow\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037693/convert-java-application-to-mac-os-x-app)
[Signing your apps for Gatekeeper](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/)
AppleJavaExtensions