# How to wrap Java JAR in OS X App Bundle?

Tags: java, jar, app-bundle

Apple's Jar Bundler utility is now pretty much discontinued it seems. I have an executable JAR file that I would simply like to wrap in an app bundle with an icon. I created a console application in Xcode (C++), and was able to run the JAR with an absolute directory by simply using the `system(constant char*)`. However, I don't know how to run a JAR bundled within the app. In the project's main folder, I have main.cpp and my JAR--how can I execute it? The language doesn't matter to me; I'll happily throw out main.cpp for a Swift or Objective-C file.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable

Comment: @jdv I don't know how to use Gradle or Maven but I suppose I will learn one of them if I can't get an answer to my question.

Comment: There are a few different native launchers for Java out there. "osxappbundle" seems to be the one all the cool kids are using for OS X.