# Convert .jar to .app using windows 7

Tags: java, macos

Hello I've created a java app using eclipse on windows, but I want to use my jar on both operating systems : Windows and Mac
Does anybody have a solution to do that using windows OS?

Comment: This is Java: you can execute that JAR on any machine with a JVM.

Comment: I know but my app will be executed by a client how can he do that?

Comment: What kind of client?  Call "Java -jar" of course.

Comment: First Thank for you response, I mean that my client is using mac and he want just to double click the app to run it

Comment: That's a central point of Java: The JVMs are System-dependent, the jars are (or at least should not) be OS-dependent. The JVM that you install is the bridge between the java world and the mac world or Microsoft world or Linux world. This is only void if you are using native implementations inside your jar that do not include binaries for the desired host OS. Or if you use dependencies that do so.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable

Answer (score 0):

IzPack has a tool called izpack2app that should take care of wrapping the jar into an app.  In fact, you can use IzPack to install your java app on most operating systems.