# Custom URL Scheme Handling with Java

Tags: java, macos, scala, jvm

I'm building a desktop application for macOS and Windows (that's down the road). For the first time, I'll be using Scala + some legacy Java instead of Swift or Objective-C. I'm trying to figure out how to get my Jar to register itself and then handle a custom URL Scheme ie "company://path/to/reasource/".

Can anyone point me in the right direction? macOS is the priority right now.

If the Java can't do this OOTB I'll probably make a helper executable in Swift that pipes data that launches/pipes data into the Jar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my research when I was facing the same problem , I found out a .jar cannot be run using a custom url scheme. I am guessing because of user permissions on the machine.

What I ended up doing was converting my jar to an executable file , in my case .exe and it ended up working fine.

In mac you should create a .dmg
In windows use launch4j to create an .exe [launch4j plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/952/launch4j-integration)

[Convert .jar to an OSX executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable)

hope it helps.