# Mac OS (UNIDENTIFIED DEVELOPER)

Tags: java, macos, jar, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I have build a JAR file, I have a tool that converts this JAR file to .pkg file which can be distributed on MAC OS.

Unfortunately, when I try to run the installed JAR file I get UNIDENTIFIED DEVELOPER message because of MAC OS GateKeeper.

I have searched through the web and I recognised that code signing is required to pass this issue. However, in windows I know the steps for code signing, but I'm not expert in MAC OS.

Do I need to convert the JAR into app first using appbundler followed by codesign? or this is an old way and there's a newest one.

What's the best solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a great answer in the following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable?noredirect=1&lq=1) that introduces [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html) as a great tool that will help you to package your executable JAR file into .pkg or .dmg.

further, you have to take a look at this [tutorial](https://centerkey.com/mac/java/) that will help you to use the javapackager to get your final output.

Answer (score -1):

Really want to disable gatekeeper?
 SOLUTION
open terminal and enter "spctl --master-disable #gatekeeper", without the quotes.
THIS ACTUALLY WORKS!
Forget what earlier posts says... None of their 'tips' or 'tricks' worked for me.

Comment: Hi thialia, i believe its better to answer on the pretex of op want to sign his JAR instead of disabling the Gatekeeper - which probably not the best idea.

Comment: I agree with @BagusTesa comment. Disabling Gatekeeper is just not a good practice on macOS and should not be considered a solution so a problem.