# Can someone help me how to create a executable file/ app/utility using java programs files in mac computer?

Tags: java, macos, jar

Need to create a jar file of 3/4 .java files and then create an executable file which just need to be double clicked to  run the main program in mac PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert .jar to an OSX executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable)

Comment: a jar file is an executable. Just saying

Comment: What is jar file of 3/4, can you explain it ?

Comment: @Sambit, 3 or 4 `.java` files.

Comment: @Stultuske: Not quite - you can execute it, but it is not ["executable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) - it does not fit Mac's ABI, can't slap hashbang on it, `x` bit doesn't work on it, you must execute it by passing it into the `java` executable. Effectively, until it hits a JVM, it's data, not executable.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to compile your .java source files to .class files and potentially package them into a .jar file. One of your classes must have a `main` method so it can be run as a Java application.

I believe there are commercial products to create executable binaries but take a look at the GraalVM native-image tool. This tool can create an executable binary for Linux or Mac from a jar file.

Comment: thanks. I will check