# How to convert jar file into application for macOS

Tags: java

I have code opened in intellij idea also I've compiled .jar how I can convert this program into .app
so It will be runnable as normal app?
Thanks

I've made jar file.

Comment: You can take a look into the accepted answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable

Comment: Try this cool new thing - https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/guides/build-native-executable-from-jar/